# How to execute system command in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, system-calls

I have one utility in php and want to be executed on pressing button in javascript.

Button in HTML:

```
<button id ="back">Zoom-Out</button></td>
```

**JS code:**

```
   $("#back").click(function() {

                exec ("php recordgenerator.php 0");   /*generate sample.json   */             
                $.getJSON('sample.json', function(data) {
                        options.series = data;
                        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
        });
```

But exec is not working in javascript. How can i execute php scirpt to update the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about using jQuery to execute AJAX calls here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

So for example you might write something similar to this:

```
$("#back").click(function() {
    $.get( "/path/to/recordgenerator.php?recordID=0", function( data ) {
      $( ".result" ).html( data );
      alert( "Load was performed." );
    });
});
```

Of course, you'll have to be running an HTTP server that hosts your PHP code. But I assume you have that already.

Comment: but my function don't return anything but write on server one file sample.json. How can i read that file.

Comment: In your PHP code just `print` the JSON string. Then your JavaScript function will receive it as the data parameter.

Comment: I just checked parameter value cannot be retrieved at the other end (recordgenerator.php). I am using $_POST["recordID"] but i don't get anything.

Comment: Ah, that's because you're issuing a GET command, not a POST command. Check this documentation for how to retrieve the GET parameters: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript, in a browser, cannot execute arbitrary programs on the visitor's system. That would be a horrific security hole.

You can use [the `XMLHttpRequest` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) to make an HTTP request to a server, and then have a server side program do whatever it is you wish to do.

Comment: I am newbie can some pls post an example here

Comment: Writing introductory tutorials for either of XMLHttpRequest or for server side programming would be too broad a subject for a stackoverflow answer.